# python: input by user to load csv with semicolon as delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, input

Simple code that ask the user what delimiter character is used in a csv file

```
def func(a,b):
    return pd.read_csv('%s.csv'%a,sep='%s'%b)
if __name__=='__main__':
    aa=input('filename: ')
    bb=input('file delimiter: ')
    func(aa,bb)
```

My input for b should be `;`

However I am not able to make it work

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: i am getting "unicodedecodeerror" i dont know what it means

if I type ';' it says that python engine dont support regex separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `encoding='utf-8'` to your code: `return pd.read_csv('%s.csv' % a, sep='%s' % b, encoding='utf-8')`